# Retrieve cross objects child from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get `weight` and `quantity` from `Cat1` where `item_name`, `date` and `branch` are same in `Cat2` in Firebase Realtime DB. But I don't know how to check conditions for that.

**JSON**

```
"Cat1" : {
    "-LBBWypuYLVn-aDYWK-N" : {
      "branch" : "b1",
      "date" : "28/Apr/2018",
      "weight" : "46",
      "item_name" : "item1",
      "quantity" : "20"
    },
    "-LBBZKUlEJB-HdiKftoj" : {
      "branch" : "b2",
      "date" : "28/Apr/2018",
      "weight" : "112",
      "item_name" : "item2",
      "quantity" : "16"
    }
  },
"Cat2" : {
    "-LBBWQcC3acYk-OOiX3T" : {
      "branch" : "b1",
      "date" : "28/Apr/2018",
      "item_name" : "item1",
      "weight" : "2.7",
      "quantity" : "20"
    }
  }
```

So far I have done the following:

```
mFishQuery = mFishRef.orderByChild("date").equalTo(mawStock.getDate());
//        mFishQuery = mFishRef.orderByKey();//.equalTo(mawStock.getDate());
//        Query fishWeight = mFishQuery.orderByChild("item_name").equalTo(mawStock.getItem_name()).getRef().orderByChild("quantity").equalTo(mawStock.getQuantity());
mFishQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        mWeightF = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("fish_weight").getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

mFishRef.child("date").equalTo(mawStock.getDate()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: yeah, i m working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem with the help of `@Peter Hadad`'s answer with some modification in his answer.

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cat1");
ref.orderByChild("item_name").equalTo("item1").addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

        DatabaseReference refer=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cat1");
        refer.orderByChild("date").equalTo(date).addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                    for (Datasnapshot ds : dataSnapshot) {

                        List<Datasnapshot> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        list.add(ds);

                        //compare data and apply logic

                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cat2");
ref.orderByChild("item_name").equalTo("item1").addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
  @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
 for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    String date=datas.child("date").getValue().toString();

    DatabaseReference refer=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cat1");
    refer.orderByChild("date").equalTo(date).addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
         @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       //retrieve data
      }
        @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

       }
      });
    }

  @Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

 }
});
```

When you query, you can only use one child so one `orderByChild()` or `orderByKey()`

So, here you have the datasnapshot at child `Cat2` then you query `where item_name=item1` and you retrieve the `date` from the database.

Then you add a nested listener and do a query `where date= date_retrieved`, and retrieve the data of Cat1.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, buddy. It helped me get some logic to move further. But still I am unable to fulfill the condition.

Comment: Which condition do you mean?

Comment: Like `cat1.item_name=cat2.item_name` and `cat1.date=cat2.date` and `cat1.quantity=cat2.quantity`.

Comment: yes that is mostly because you can only use one `orderByChild()`, you may need to change the database a bit. But in the above, it checks if item_name is equal to item1 in cat1 and retrieves the other data example date. Then it checks if cat1 has the same date(as cat2) , so it retrieves the data of cat1

Comment: Cool. Now i got it. I have to add 1 more listener to fulfill this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170017/discussion-between-mohammedsalim-shivani-and-peter-haddad).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just have to do enough `itr.next()` until the iterator is at the nth position (where `n` is the random number from `nextInt()`) and then you can simply get the Object you want with `getValue()`, the example below should show it well:

[image: Sample data]

Solution to get random generated keys.

```
questionsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("questions").child("DE");

questionsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int questionCount = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        int rand = random.nextInt(questionCount);
        Iterator itr = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

        for(int i = 0; i < rand; i++) {
            itr.next();
        }
        childSnapshot = (DataSnapshot) itr.next();
        question = childSnapshot.getValue(Question.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```